# Can the periodic extension of a $\sin$/$\cos$ Fourier series be infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I understand that a piecewise smooth function will have a Fourier series that converges to the periodic extension of the function (Like $-L$ to $L$, or $0$ to $\pi$, etc.) before repeating over and over that area. Can an infinite area for the periodic extension be chosen on the real number line $(-\infty,\infty)$?

In that case, the fourier series would reduce to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ with $A_i$ being the coefficient for the cosine term, as $\cos(0)=1$ and $\sin(0)=0$. Then the fourier series isn't a function of $x$ and only a constant so I think it isn't possible? Or maybe only possible to a desired finite length?

Comment: yes, it is the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), it is "much more" complicated, and no you won't be able to prove the [Fourier inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) as the limiting case when $T \to \infty$ of the Fourier series for $f(x)$ restricted to $[-T,T]$.

Comment: So basically "yes, but it's complicated"? I find the wikipedia page of a fourier transform hard to understand. I suppose it's too advanced for me right now but basically you can take a fourier transform and use the fourier inversion theorem to get a fourier series with an infinite periodic extension?

Comment: from the Fourier transform you won't get a Fourier series (unless the function is periodic in that case the Fourier transform is more or less the same as the coefficients of Fourier series) : when the function is not periodic, it becomes $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty C(\xi)e^{2i\pi \xi x} d \xi$ instead of  $f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2i\pi n x/T}$ when it is $T$ periodic. you see that the coefficients $c_n$, one for every integer frequency $n /T$, become a function of "all" the possible frequencies $\xi$ in the non-periodic case. (and that the $\sum_n$ is replaced by an $\int d\xi$)